# Conditional Filling and Formatting NAs in R

Tags: r, if-statement, na, missing-data, chron

I downloaded the play-by-play from last year's Superbowl, and am having trouble conditionally replacing and formatting `NA`s.

I am primary concerned with the following two vectors in my dataframe:

```
> superbowl$Quarter
  [1] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
 [18] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2 
 [35] 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
 [52] 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
 [69] 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3 
 [86] 3  3  3  3     3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
[103] 3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
[120] 3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4 
[137] 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4 
[154] 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4     4  4  4 
[171] 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  OT OT OT OT OT OT OT OT
[188] OT OT
Levels:  1 2 3 4 OT
> str(superbowl$Quarter)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "","1","2","3",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

> superbowl$Time
  [1] 15:00 15:00 14:55 14:26 13:47 13:37 12:55 12:16
  [9] 11:32 10:41 10:28 9:56  9:22  8:38  7:56  7:15 
 [17] 6:36  5:55  5:48  5:14  5:08  4:25  3:45  3:04 
 [25] 2:27  1:48  1:36  0:58  0:24  15:00 14:19 14:08
 [33] 13:29 13:11 12:46 12:20 12:20 12:15 12:15 12:10
 [41] 12:04 11:17 10:45 10:37 10:11 9:45  9:00  8:55 
 [49] 8:48  8:48  8:48  8:48  8:12  8:07  8:02  7:34 
 [57] 6:53  6:10  6:01  5:20  5:16  5:16  5:12  4:36 
 [65] 3:59  3:23  2:36        2:21  2:21  2:00  1:43 
 [73] 1:43  1:37  0:59  0:33  0:30  0:23  0:23  0:18 
 [81] 0:12  0:05  0:05  0:02  15:00 14:54 14:11 13:24
 [89] 13:19       13:07 13:02 12:57 12:57 12:52 12:45
 [97] 12:07 11:36 11:06 10:26 9:57  9:28  8:43  8:36 
[105] 8:31  8:31  8:31  7:51  7:13  6:46  6:12  6:04 
[113] 5:35  4:54  4:49  4:07  3:17  2:43  2:12  2:06 
[121] 2:06  2:05  1:30  0:59  0:59  0:52  0:04  15:00
[129] 14:51 14:29 14:00 13:21 13:13 12:47 12:24 12:20
[137] 11:48 11:07 10:25 9:48  9:44  9:40  9:00  8:31 
[145] 8:24  7:41  7:03  6:34  6:00  5:56  5:56  5:53 
[153] 5:18  4:47  4:40  3:56  3:50  3:50  3:44  3:38 
[161] 3:30  3:24  3:17  2:38  2:34  2:28        2:03 
[169] 1:57  1:25  1:00  0:57  0:57  0:52  0:32  0:19 
[177] 0:18  0:11  0:03  15:00 15:00 14:26 13:59 13:12
[185] 12:37 11:56 11:18 11:13 11:08
155 Levels:  0:02 0:03 0:04 0:05 0:11 0:12 0:18 ... 9:57
> str(superbowl$Time)
 Factor w/ 155 levels "","0:02","0:03",..: 79 79 78 74 68 67 56 48 40 32 ...
```

The relationship between `superbowl$Quarter` and `superbowl$Time` is that, for each observation, `superbowl$Time` is the time left in the quarter that `superbowl$Quarter` represents. I would like `superbowl$Time` to represent, instead of time remaining in the quarter, time remaining in the game, so that there is a constant standard of measurement between plays of different quarters. To do this, I've written the following code (where `superbowl$Time.1` is simply a variable I've created to test this out without altering the original vector):

```
library(chron)
superbowl$Time <- ms(as.character(superbowl$Time))
superbowl$Time.1 <- (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time
```

The conversion works perfectly well, except in instances where `superbowl$Quarter == "OT"` and of missing values (instances of missing values occure in `superbowl$Time` when there's a challenge or an extra point). In both cases, R converts the value to `NA`:

```
library(chron)
> superbowl$Time <- ms(as.character(superbowl$Time))
> superbowl$Time.1 <- (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> superbowl$Time.1
  [1] "60M 0S"  "60M 0S"  "59M 55S" "59M 26S" "58M 47S"
  [6] "58M 37S" "57M 55S" "57M 16S" "56M 32S" "55M 41S"
 [11] "55M 28S" "54M 56S" "54M 22S" "53M 38S" "52M 56S"
 [16] "52M 15S" "51M 36S" "50M 55S" "50M 48S" "50M 14S"
 [21] "50M 8S"  "49M 25S" "48M 45S" "48M 4S"  "47M 27S"
 [26] "46M 48S" "46M 36S" "45M 58S" "45M 24S" "45M 0S" 
 [31] "44M 19S" "44M 8S"  "43M 29S" "43M 11S" "42M 46S"
 [36] "42M 20S" "42M 20S" "42M 15S" "42M 15S" "42M 10S"
 [41] "42M 4S"  "41M 17S" "40M 45S" "40M 37S" "40M 11S"
 [46] "39M 45S" "39M 0S"  "38M 55S" "38M 48S" "38M 48S"
 [51] "38M 48S" "38M 48S" "38M 12S" "38M 7S"  "38M 2S" 
 [56] "37M 34S" "36M 53S" "36M 10S" "36M 1S"  "35M 20S"
 [61] "35M 16S" "35M 16S" "35M 12S" "34M 36S" "33M 59S"
 [66] "33M 23S" "32M 36S" NA        "32M 21S" "32M 21S"
 [71] "32M 0S"  "31M 43S" "31M 43S" "31M 37S" "30M 59S"
 [76] "30M 33S" "30M 30S" "30M 23S" "30M 23S" "30M 18S"
 [81] "30M 12S" "30M 5S"  "30M 5S"  "30M 2S"  "30M 0S" 
 [86] "29M 54S" "29M 11S" "28M 24S" "28M 19S" NA       
 [91] "28M 7S"  "28M 2S"  "27M 57S" "27M 57S" "27M 52S"
 [96] "27M 45S" "27M 7S"  "26M 36S" "26M 6S"  "25M 26S"
[101] "24M 57S" "24M 28S" "23M 43S" "23M 36S" "23M 31S"
[106] "23M 31S" "23M 31S" "22M 51S" "22M 13S" "21M 46S"
[111] "21M 12S" "21M 4S"  "20M 35S" "19M 54S" "19M 49S"
[116] "19M 7S"  "18M 17S" "17M 43S" "17M 12S" "17M 6S" 
[121] "17M 6S"  "17M 5S"  "16M 30S" "15M 59S" "15M 59S"
[126] "15M 52S" "15M 4S"  "15M 0S"  "14M 51S" "14M 29S"
[131] "14M 0S"  "13M 21S" "13M 13S" "12M 47S" "12M 24S"
[136] "12M 20S" "11M 48S" "11M 7S"  "10M 25S" "9M 48S" 
[141] "9M 44S"  "9M 40S"  "9M 0S"   "8M 31S"  "8M 24S" 
[146] "7M 41S"  "7M 3S"   "6M 34S"  "6M 0S"   "5M 56S" 
[151] "5M 56S"  "5M 53S"  "5M 18S"  "4M 47S"  "4M 40S" 
[156] "3M 56S"  "3M 50S"  "3M 50S"  "3M 44S"  "3M 38S" 
[161] "3M 30S"  "3M 24S"  "3M 17S"  "2M 38S"  "2M 34S" 
[166] "2M 28S"  NA        "2M 3S"   "1M 57S"  "1M 25S" 
[171] "1M 0S"   "57S"     "57S"     "52S"     "32S"    
[176] "19S"     "18S"     "11S"     "3S"      NA       
[181] NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
[186] NA        NA        NA        NA
```

I need help conditionally replacing and formatting these `NA`s. What I would like is, in instances where `superbowl$Quarter == "OT"`, to leave the value as-is. In instances of missing values, I would like to fill them with `superbowl$Time`'s value from the previous observation.

To address the overtime problem, I came up with this:

```
library(chron)
superbowl$Time <- ms(as.character(superbowl$Time))
superbowl$Time.1 <- ifelse(superbowl$Quarter == "OT", superbowl$Time, (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time)
```

While both arguments, `superbowl$Time.1 <- superbowl$Time` and `superbowl$Time.1 <- (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time`, work as desired individually:

```
> superbowl$Time.1 <- superbowl$Time
> superbowl$Time.1
  [1] "15M 0S"  "15M 0S"  "14M 55S" "14M 26S" "13M 47S"
  [6] "13M 37S" "12M 55S" "12M 16S" "11M 32S" "10M 41S"
 [11] "10M 28S" "9M 56S"  "9M 22S"  "8M 38S"  "7M 56S" 
 [16] "7M 15S"  "6M 36S"  "5M 55S"  "5M 48S"  "5M 14S" 
 [21] "5M 8S"   "4M 25S"  "3M 45S"  "3M 4S"   "2M 27S" 
 [26] "1M 48S"  "1M 36S"  "58S"     "24S"     "15M 0S" 
 [31] "14M 19S" "14M 8S"  "13M 29S" "13M 11S" "12M 46S"
 [36] "12M 20S" "12M 20S" "12M 15S" "12M 15S" "12M 10S"
 [41] "12M 4S"  "11M 17S" "10M 45S" "10M 37S" "10M 11S"
 [46] "9M 45S"  "9M 0S"   "8M 55S"  "8M 48S"  "8M 48S" 
 [51] "8M 48S"  "8M 48S"  "8M 12S"  "8M 7S"   "8M 2S"  
 [56] "7M 34S"  "6M 53S"  "6M 10S"  "6M 1S"   "5M 20S" 
 [61] "5M 16S"  "5M 16S"  "5M 12S"  "4M 36S"  "3M 59S" 
 [66] "3M 23S"  "2M 36S"  NA        "2M 21S"  "2M 21S" 
 [71] "2M 0S"   "1M 43S"  "1M 43S"  "1M 37S"  "59S"    
 [76] "33S"     "30S"     "23S"     "23S"     "18S"    
 [81] "12S"     "5S"      "5S"      "2S"      "15M 0S" 
 [86] "14M 54S" "14M 11S" "13M 24S" "13M 19S" NA       
 [91] "13M 7S"  "13M 2S"  "12M 57S" "12M 57S" "12M 52S"
 [96] "12M 45S" "12M 7S"  "11M 36S" "11M 6S"  "10M 26S"
[101] "9M 57S"  "9M 28S"  "8M 43S"  "8M 36S"  "8M 31S" 
[106] "8M 31S"  "8M 31S"  "7M 51S"  "7M 13S"  "6M 46S" 
[111] "6M 12S"  "6M 4S"   "5M 35S"  "4M 54S"  "4M 49S" 
[116] "4M 7S"   "3M 17S"  "2M 43S"  "2M 12S"  "2M 6S"  
[121] "2M 6S"   "2M 5S"   "1M 30S"  "59S"     "59S"    
[126] "52S"     "4S"      "15M 0S"  "14M 51S" "14M 29S"
[131] "14M 0S"  "13M 21S" "13M 13S" "12M 47S" "12M 24S"
[136] "12M 20S" "11M 48S" "11M 7S"  "10M 25S" "9M 48S" 
[141] "9M 44S"  "9M 40S"  "9M 0S"   "8M 31S"  "8M 24S" 
[146] "7M 41S"  "7M 3S"   "6M 34S"  "6M 0S"   "5M 56S" 
[151] "5M 56S"  "5M 53S"  "5M 18S"  "4M 47S"  "4M 40S" 
[156] "3M 56S"  "3M 50S"  "3M 50S"  "3M 44S"  "3M 38S" 
[161] "3M 30S"  "3M 24S"  "3M 17S"  "2M 38S"  "2M 34S" 
[166] "2M 28S"  NA        "2M 3S"   "1M 57S"  "1M 25S" 
[171] "1M 0S"   "57S"     "57S"     "52S"     "32S"    
[176] "19S"     "18S"     "11S"     "3S"      "15M 0S" 
[181] "15M 0S"  "14M 26S" "13M 59S" "13M 12S" "12M 37S"
[186] "11M 56S" "11M 18S" "11M 13S" "11M 8S" 

> superbowl$Time.1 <- (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> superbowl$Time.1
  [1] "60M 0S"  "60M 0S"  "59M 55S" "59M 26S" "58M 47S"
  [6] "58M 37S" "57M 55S" "57M 16S" "56M 32S" "55M 41S"
 [11] "55M 28S" "54M 56S" "54M 22S" "53M 38S" "52M 56S"
 [16] "52M 15S" "51M 36S" "50M 55S" "50M 48S" "50M 14S"
 [21] "50M 8S"  "49M 25S" "48M 45S" "48M 4S"  "47M 27S"
 [26] "46M 48S" "46M 36S" "45M 58S" "45M 24S" "45M 0S" 
 [31] "44M 19S" "44M 8S"  "43M 29S" "43M 11S" "42M 46S"
 [36] "42M 20S" "42M 20S" "42M 15S" "42M 15S" "42M 10S"
 [41] "42M 4S"  "41M 17S" "40M 45S" "40M 37S" "40M 11S"
 [46] "39M 45S" "39M 0S"  "38M 55S" "38M 48S" "38M 48S"
 [51] "38M 48S" "38M 48S" "38M 12S" "38M 7S"  "38M 2S" 
 [56] "37M 34S" "36M 53S" "36M 10S" "36M 1S"  "35M 20S"
 [61] "35M 16S" "35M 16S" "35M 12S" "34M 36S" "33M 59S"
 [66] "33M 23S" "32M 36S" NA        "32M 21S" "32M 21S"
 [71] "32M 0S"  "31M 43S" "31M 43S" "31M 37S" "30M 59S"
 [76] "30M 33S" "30M 30S" "30M 23S" "30M 23S" "30M 18S"
 [81] "30M 12S" "30M 5S"  "30M 5S"  "30M 2S"  "30M 0S" 
 [86] "29M 54S" "29M 11S" "28M 24S" "28M 19S" NA       
 [91] "28M 7S"  "28M 2S"  "27M 57S" "27M 57S" "27M 52S"
 [96] "27M 45S" "27M 7S"  "26M 36S" "26M 6S"  "25M 26S"
[101] "24M 57S" "24M 28S" "23M 43S" "23M 36S" "23M 31S"
[106] "23M 31S" "23M 31S" "22M 51S" "22M 13S" "21M 46S"
[111] "21M 12S" "21M 4S"  "20M 35S" "19M 54S" "19M 49S"
[116] "19M 7S"  "18M 17S" "17M 43S" "17M 12S" "17M 6S" 
[121] "17M 6S"  "17M 5S"  "16M 30S" "15M 59S" "15M 59S"
[126] "15M 52S" "15M 4S"  "15M 0S"  "14M 51S" "14M 29S"
[131] "14M 0S"  "13M 21S" "13M 13S" "12M 47S" "12M 24S"
[136] "12M 20S" "11M 48S" "11M 7S"  "10M 25S" "9M 48S" 
[141] "9M 44S"  "9M 40S"  "9M 0S"   "8M 31S"  "8M 24S" 
[146] "7M 41S"  "7M 3S"   "6M 34S"  "6M 0S"   "5M 56S" 
[151] "5M 56S"  "5M 53S"  "5M 18S"  "4M 47S"  "4M 40S" 
[156] "3M 56S"  "3M 50S"  "3M 50S"  "3M 44S"  "3M 38S" 
[161] "3M 30S"  "3M 24S"  "3M 17S"  "2M 38S"  "2M 34S" 
[166] "2M 28S"  NA        "2M 3S"   "1M 57S"  "1M 25S" 
[171] "1M 0S"   "57S"     "57S"     "52S"     "32S"    
[176] "19S"     "18S"     "11S"     "3S"      NA       
[181] NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
[186] NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Together, in the `ifelse()` function, they do not:

```
> superbowl$Time.1 <- ifelse(superbowl$Quarter == "OT", superbowl$Time, (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time)
Warning message:
In ifelse(superbowl$Quarter == "OT", superbowl$Time, (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter))) *  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> superbowl$Time.1
  [1]  0  0 55 26 47 37 55 16 32 41 28 56 22 38 56 15 36
 [18] 55 48 14  8 25 45  4 27 48 36 58 24  0 19  8 29 11
 [35] 46 20 20 15 15 10  4 17 45 37 11 45  0 55 48 48 48
 [52] 48 12  7  2 34 53 10  1 20 16 16 12 36 59 23 36 NA
 [69] 21 21  0 43 43 37 59 33 30 23 23 18 12  5  5  2  0
 [86] 54 11 24 19 NA  7  2 57 57 52 45  7 36  6 26 57 28
[103] 43 36 31 31 31 51 13 46 12  4 35 54 49  7 17 43 12
[120]  6  6  5 30 59 59 52  4  0 51 29  0 21 13 47 24 20
[137] 48  7 25 48 44 40  0 31 24 41  3 34  0 56 56 53 18
[154] 47 40 56 50 50 44 38 30 24 17 38 34 28 NA  3 57 25
[171]  0 57 57 52 32 19 18 11  3  0  0 26 59 12 37 56 18
[188] 13  8
```

I don't know what these numbers are or where they came from. They are also not formatted properly.

What is the `ifelse()` function doing to my code? How do I get `superbowl$Time.1` to output `(4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time)` in quarters 1-4 and `superbowl$Time` in overtime?

To address the problem of missing values, I came up with the following function:

```
f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 'OT'){
  df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
    ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), superbowl$Time[-1], 
           i))
  return(df)
}
superbowl = f1(superbowl, cols = c('Time.1'), match_with = superbowl$Quarter)
```

I suspect this will work, but the problem here is I don't know how to reference the previous observation in a function (observation i-1, when i represents each given observation on which the function is operating). Referencing said observation is what I was trying to do where I wrote `superbowl$Time[-1]` above. This does not work. It results in the same string of numbers the `ifelse()` function produced:

```
library(chron)
> superbowl$Time <- ms(as.character(superbowl$Time))
> superbowl$Time.1 <- (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 'OT'){
+   df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
+     ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), superbowl$Time[-1], 
+            i))
+   return(df)
+ }
> superbowl = f1(superbowl, cols = c('Time.1'), match_with = superbowl$Quarter)
> 
> superbowl$Time.1
  [1]  0  0 55 26 47 37 55 16 32 41 28 56 22 38 56 15 36
 [18] 55 48 14  8 25 45  4 27 48 36 58 24  0 19  8 29 11
 [35] 46 20 20 15 15 10  4 17 45 37 11 45  0 55 48 48 48
 [52] 48 12  7  2 34 53 10  1 20 16 16 12 36 59 23 36 NA
 [69] 21 21  0 43 43 37 59 33 30 23 23 18 12  5  5  2  0
 [86] 54 11 24 19 NA  7  2 57 57 52 45  7 36  6 26 57 28
[103] 43 36 31 31 31 51 13 46 12  4 35 54 49  7 17 43 12
[120]  6  6  5 30 59 59 52  4  0 51 29  0 21 13 47 24 20
[137] 48  7 25 48 44 40  0 31 24 41  3 34  0 56 56 53 18
[154] 47 40 56 50 50 44 38 30 24 17 38 34 28 NA  3 57 25
[171]  0 57 57 52 32 19 18 11  3  0 26 59 12 37 56 18 13
[188]  8  0
```

Is there an easy way to have a function reference the previous observation when calculating the value of the present observation? For example, observation 68 of `superbowl$Time` should be `2m 36s`, the same as observation 67 of `superbowl$Time`, and not  or `NA`.

Thank you, so much, for all your help!

Comment: I suspect the problem is this (from help for `ifelse`): returned Value is `A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no. The mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to accommodate first any values taken from yes and then any values taken from no.` As a solution, could you try using conventional `if-else` block instead of `ifelse()`?

Comment: You spit out the data at the beginning of the question, but it's hard to use it without typing it manually in order to test it out. Can you run `dput(superbowl)` and paste the output?

I suspect the following would work (comments do not format code well, so sorry for the ugliness), but I can't confirm without testing it:

`library(dplyr)
mutate(superbowl, Time.1 = case_when(
  Quarter == "OT" & !is.na(Time) ~ Time,
  Quarter == "OT" & is.na(Time) ~ lag(Time),
  Quarter != "OT" ~ (4 - as.numeric(as.character(superbowl$Quarter)))*ms("15:00") + superbowl$Time
))`